# How to get the LinqToExcel 64 bit build

Tags: linq-to-excel

Can anybody please provide me with a link to a 64-bit build of linq-to-Excel? I see references to it in several posts and on the official site (https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel), but I am unable to locate a download of the 64 bit binaries.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find this? I found a zip file from a couple years ago, but it is many versions behind the current version.

Comment: well, we decided not to go with the approach to acceptance testing that would benefit from such a component, so we don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NuGet, you have to look specifically for **LinqToExcel_x64**, it doesn't show up when you look for **LinqToExcel**

Or get the bits from the [NuGet source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel_x64/)

Comment: The name is LinqToExcel_x64